# Вопрос по JavaScript, как при клике менять содержимое

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5, вёрстка

Делаю многоуровневое меню, подскажите, пожалуйста, как на JavaScript сделать чтобы по клику на `span` с классом `submenu-caret`, крестик менялся на минус, а при повторном клике, чтобы обратно плюс становился? Спасибо

```
                                <div>
                                    <span class="submenu-caret">+</span>
                                    <a href="#">Двигатели</a>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="shop-menu-level-2">
                                    <li class="level-2">
                                        <a href="">Двигатели дизельные</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="level-2">
                                        <a href="">Двигатели бензиновые</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".submenu-caret");
el.onclick = function(e) {
  if (this.innerText == "+") {
    this.innerText = "-";
    document.querySelector(".shop-menu-level-2").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    this.innerText = "+";
    document.querySelector(".shop-menu-level-2").style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="submenu-caret">+</span>
  <a href="#">Двигатели</a>
</div>
<ul class="shop-menu-level-2" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level-2">
    <a href="">Двигатели дизельные</a>
  </li>
  <li class="level-2">
    <a href="">Двигатели бензиновые</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

В принципе тоже самое, но запись короче

```
var symbol = document.querySelector(".submenu-caret"),
    list = document.querySelector(".shop-menu-level-2");
symbol.addEventListener("click", function() {
  list.classList.toggle("block");
  result = (symbol.innerHTML == "+") ? symbol.innerHTML = "-" : symbol.innerHTML = "+"; 
});
```